# Generate a specific number of rows in MySQL (without using a table)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, rows, data-generation

How to generate a defined number of rows with an SQL query — without using a table (where these rows already exist) ?

For example, in order to return 3 rows, we could do this:

```sql
select * from (
    select 1 union all
    select 1 union all
    select 1
) t
```

Which gives this result:

|  |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |

However, this is impractical if I need to return, say, a thousand rows. Is there another way?

Comment: you could try to use the MySQL while loop https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-while-loop/

Comment: You really should be specific about the exact data you want to generate.  Do you really want 1000 records of 1s?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, i want 1000 (or any arbitrary number) records of 1s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
WITH recursive numbers AS 
(  select 1 as Numbers
   union all
   select Numbers
   from numbers
   limit 1000
 )
select * from numbers;
```

Change the limit as you need.

Another option is :

```
WITH recursive numbers AS 
(  select 1 as Numbers
   union all
   select Numbers + 1
   from numbers
   where Numbers < 1000
 )
select * from numbers;
```

You may need to increase  @@cte_max_recursion_depth to a larger value.

Tested on

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.25    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql>     WITH recursive numbers AS
    ->     (  select 1 as Numbers
    ->        union all
    ->        select Numbers
    ->        from numbers
    ->        limit 100
    ->      )
    ->     select * from numbers;
+---------+
| Numbers |
+---------+
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
+------+
100 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```